# Get the first position of the longest intersection range of two vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, stl, iterator

I'm working on a problem considering 2 vectors, which for example can be as follow:

```
std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
std::vector<int> v2 = {      3, 4,       7, 8, 9, 10};
```

If I perform std::set_intersection, it would give me the following vector:

```
std::vector<int> v3 = {3,4,7,8,9,10};
```

In this case there are 2 subranges : 3,4 and 7,8,9,10. The longest subrange is 7,8,9,10, and its first element is 7. Therefore I'd like to get the index of it in v2 = 2.

I was thinking about having an iterator and reset it to point to the first element when a longer subrange is found, then later can just use distance( v2.begin(), iter ) to get it, but can't figure it out yet. Does anyone have an idea how to do this generically ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are vectors strictly increasing?

Comment: No, just to visualise them I put it that way. But they are const and the ordering is fixed though. It's just about finding the longest intersection of both set.

Comment: Is the second vector constructed by removing some elements from the first one? Or it can contain anything?

Comment: It can contain anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Question you're looking for is** : [Longest Common contiguous subsequence](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-substring/)

**Solution using Dynamic programming** :

- Assuming `I = len(V1)` & `J = len(V2)`
- Create a table `len[I+1][J+1]` to store common subsequence so far and track Longest subsequence so far in `MaxCurrent`
- Longest subsequence For `i`th element of `V1` & `j`th element of `V2`so far is :

  - if `V1[i-1] == V2[j-1] : (len[i-1][j-1] + 1)` and update value in `MaxCurrent`
  - else 0
- Max output is `max (MaxCurrent, len[i][j])`

**Note :** Base is `len[0][j] = len[i][0] = 0`